# Android: Getting 'You must supply a layout_width attribute' although application was working fine before

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Forget about the obvious thing that I am missing both a layout_width and layout_height.

Everything was working great. I defined a base theme like this:

```
<style name="Base" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>              
    </style>
```

And I applied it to the application.

Everything was working OK and I didn't need to applied those same attributes everywhere which is annoying.

Suddenly, I am getting these errors, and usually in the layouts of the single items views of the adapters.

The only thing that I think of is that I am using `<include>` tags now, to add a toolbar.

Has anyone experienced the same thing? The solution right now is to add manually the values as I run the application and get the error.

I wanted to know if I am alone in this or should I submit a bug. 
Thanks!

Comment: Check whether you have supplied the both dimensional attributes(layout_width and layout_height) for include tag since both are required attributes and make sure you did not missed dimensional attributes layout XML file when you try to add View objects.

Comment: You know, I was trying that also. Android documentation says that only the source layout is required in the include tag. Its strange.  Would that make the layout inherit the layout properties for the children views or would that just set it for the parent view? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right.(Check the "layout_width" spelling make sure you did not mistype.)Are you still getting the problem?if then can you give your source, so I can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you inflate some view with `View.inflate(R.layout.some_view)` ? In this case, probably, the theme won't be applied.

Comment: Well, since its happening mostly in the adapter that could be the problem. I am using LayoutInflater. Can you confirm you are sure that the theme is not applied of using the inflate method? I mean, that could make the themes almost useless. Half of my XML cannot be optimized. I started with some tests and when I saw that everything worked I removed all the layout_width and layout_height from my files. Maybe I didn't test everything. Thanks!

Comment: No, I'm not sure, I just think it can be one possible reason. I also don't think layout_width and layout_height belong to a theme since they never can be meaningfully replaced by anything else (whereas, say, background color does belong to a theme because it can be replaced by another color). So maybe you will be fine if you just put layout_width and layout_height back into your xmls.

Comment: Oh I see your point. I've created a theme just to clean the XMLs. I've found another thread where they say LayoutInflater doesn't apply the theme unless you use the Activity context (I am using the Application context for everything).

Comment: The problem actually was using the application context in the inflate method, therefore the Theme was being applied. Using the Activity context solved it. Strange. Thanks